# Porting the Javascript replace() function to Objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, regex, replace, nsscanner

Im trying to port over some Javascript code into Objective C, and I'm wondering what is the best approach for the Javascript `.replace()` function.

My javascript looks like this:

```
str = str.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'_r');
```

How would I achieve this with `NSRegularExpression`?

Or would I be better off using a `NSScanner` to parse through the strings and then `replaceCharactersInRange:` to replace the characters?

Comment: Can't you do the same thing with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`?

Comment: woah - I wasnt even aware such a method existed, is this a part of NSString? And will it work on things like new lines? Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Yep! It's in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Newlines should work fine. If you just want to strip all newlines and carriage returns there's also `[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]`. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck! NSString already has `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`. It should work fine with new lines. Also, if you just want to strip all newlines and carriage returns, you can use:

```
[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

NSString comes with all kinds of things, and they are all documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).